# Induced current in a rectangular loop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electricity, electric-current

[image]

The question is

**How much heat is generated in the resistor during the loop's entire path into and out of the magnetic field? Give your answer in J.**

I used Faraday's law and managed to get the current which was 0.15A. Now I have to get the energy generated in the resistor during the loop's path.

Since the length of the magnetic field is not given in the problem, I'm confused as to how I can get the time duration of the rectangular loop spent in the B field.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Since the loop carries a charge it will experience a force while moving through the magnetic field. This will cause it to move in a curved path and come back out of the field, and so the length of the magnetic field is unnecessary.

Comment: @EdmundWitkowski then, in order to get the radius of its circular path, I'd need the mass of the rectangular loop which is not given, right? Do I have all the information I need to get the energy?

Answer (score 1):

Only when the magnetic flux is changing will there be an induced emf.
This happens as the loop enters the region where there is a magnetic field and when it leaves that region.

The magnetic flux changes at a constant rate so the induced emf is constant which means that the induced current is constant so the power dissipated as heat in the circuit is also constant.

With the given data you can also work out for how long the emf is being induced.

Comment: Can you give me some hint on how I might work out for how long the emf is being induced?

Comment: All the time that the magnetic flux is changing as the loop is entering the region of magnetic field and leaving the region of magnetic field.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure how to get it... How can I figure out when and where the loop enters and exists? I know what trajectory it's gona follow and that's pretty much it.

Comment: Do I just do l/velocity = 0.02 sec?